# Reverse function strange behaviour when scroll

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have this typescript code :

```
get history() {
    return this.isCollapsed
        ? this.service.history.reverse().slice(0, this.SHOW)
        : this.service.history.reverse();
}
```

In template :

```
<div *ngFor="let histor of history">
   <div{{ histor.name }}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I scroll these 2 items that exist in `history` are changed with the place, and I get a kind of freezing. So strange behaviour. Is the reverse method the cause of that ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: what is `this.service.history.reverse()` this method, please provide detailed code

Comment: may be try `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` for non-freezing result

Comment: It seems that the page make an re-render on scroll and I don't understand why